# Angular2: Component composed of multiples directives

Tags: angular

Version: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6"

We assume that we have two `@Directive`

- `HighLightDirective`
- `UnderlineDirective`

How can I create a `@Component` that implements this two `@Directive`?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '{{text}}',
    //Looking from something like that..
    //using: [HighLightDirective, UnderlineDirective]
})
export class TestComponent {
    public text:string;
    //maybe? constructor(hightlight,underline)
}
```

PS: I know that I can do this by changing the Component template like below. Does something more elegant exists ?

```
'<div highlight underline>{{text}}</div>'
```

Comment: That's exactly what the directives are for, and how you should use them (: The example you give `{{ text }}` is kinda trivial, for everything else attribute directives are good solution. Do you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: @Sasxa I'm quite confused about adding a div container on each Component I made. It creates `<test><div>my_text</div></test>` when `<test>my_text</test>` looks much easier :]

Comment: Use `<test highlight underline></test>` in parent template.

Comment: In fact I don't want to allow instances of TestComponent without this two directives, that why this solution could not work too.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question asks for. What should the effect of composing be?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same selector for the directives and the component.

```
@Directive({selector: 'test'})
class HighlightDirective {
}

@Directive({selector: 'test'})
class UnderlineDirective {}

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    directives: []
    template: '{{text}}',
    //Looking from something like that..
    //using: [HighLightDirective, UnderlineDirective]
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(@Self()hs:HighlightDirective, @Self()hs:UnderlineDirective) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [TestComponent,HighlightDirective, UnderlineDirective]
  template: `
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <test></test>

`
})
export class App {

}
```

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NWRJ7G?p=preview)**

If you want to use the directives independendly of the component you can add multiple selectors like

```
@Directive({selector: 'test,highlight'})
class HighlightDirective {
}
```

The constructor throws when `HighlightDirective` and `UnderlineDirective` are not applied

```
  constructor(@Self()hs:HighlightDirective, @Self()hs:UnderlineDirective) {}
```

You can also add the directives to `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`

```
bootstrap(MyComponent, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [HighlightDirective, UnderlineDirective], multi:true})]);
```

to get them applied everywhere where the selector matches, without adding them to `directives: [HighlightDirective, UnderlineDirective]` of every component where you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Looking from something like that..
//using: [HighLightDirective, UnderlineDirective]
```

What you're looking for is the [`directives`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html) property:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div highlight underline>{{text}}</div>',
    directives: [HighLightDirective, UnderlineDirective] // don't forget to import them!
})
export class TestComponent {
    @Input() // don't forget this!
    public text:string;
    constructor() {} //no need to do anything here
}
```

I misunderstood your question initially and thought you were just confused about the metadata key to use - if you are, then see above.

In terms of "automatically" applying these directives to the component template, IMHO there's nothing inelegant about applying them them in the template as you have, and anything "more elegant" would be proportionally less clear. In any case, no, there is no alternative, and doing what you're doing here is perfectly idiomatic.

This is all assuming your actual use case is more complex than this question, otherwise (since you're not adding anything new in your template) `Component` is the wrong tool here and you should simply apply the two directives directly. If you're *really* dead-set against doing that and your use case is actually this simple, I suppose

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: '<div highlight underline><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
    directives: [HighLightDirective, UnderlineDirective] 
})
export class TestComponent { }
```

which you could then use as: `<test>stuff</test>` rather than `<test [text]="someVar"></test>` would be more elegant... but it still doesn't make much sense to me.